# How to specify the output directory for Dart's "pub deploy"?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

With Dart's "pub" tool and its "deploy" command, you can create a deployable version of your Dart web application.  The output is written to the "deploy" directory.  I want to know if there's a way to specify a different output directory?

I searched the internet for a command-line option, but found no mention of it.  Running "pub help deploy" shows no options for the deploy command.

If "pub deploy" has no output directory option, I want to find the pub.dart source code. I'll create a customized version that accepts an output directory option.  Unfortunately, I can't find pub.dart in the SDK.  I found the pub shell script.  It calls pub.dart.snapshot, which is 100 thousand lines of unintelligible Dart bytecode.  Is there a human readable pub.dart file?  Is it in the SDK?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, this is not configurable. The *source* folder is always `/web` and the *output* folder is always `/deploy`.

The source is available at http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/trunk/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/command/deploy.dart#33 .

A simple workaround is just to rename `deploy` once generated.